# How can I return an attribute value with argument?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I am just starting working with VueJS. I use Quasar framework, with [its input component that provides an error state](https://quasar-framework.org/components/input-textfield.html#Error-State)

```
<q-field :error="error" error-label="Oh buggers! You made a boo boo.">
   <q-input v-model="text" float-label="Colored with Error" color="amber"  />
</q-field>
```

I use [Vualidate](https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/) to check several inputs in a form, and I want to return as `error-label` value a contextualized and localized version of the error text.

With Blaze, I would have used an helper with argument, eg `error-label="{{getError 'email'}}"` that would have looked like this (untested code):

```
  getError(input) {
    let firstError = ""
    _.each(this.$v[input], function(validator) {
      if (!validator) { // eg. validator = 'required'
        firstError = i18n.__('input_error' + validator, {
          input
        }) // eg. firstError = 'The email field is required'
        break
      }
    })
    return firstError
  },
```

I'm not sure of the right way to do it in VueJS. I noticed that the v-bind directive can take arguments, but I do not know how (the docs are mentioning it without example) nor if it is the right way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Quasar framework docs `error-label` is prop and you can just write binding like this:

```
:error-label="getError('email')"
```